# Is it possible to create thumbnails for different file formats (psd, pdf, ai, tif, eps) using ASP.Net

Tags: .net, image, jpeg, thumbnails

I have a requirement to develop web app for the creation of thumbnails for psd, pdf, ai, tif and eps image formats?
Is it possible in .Net? The GetThumbnailImage generates thumbnails for JPG images and it reduces the size of the image with poor quality.

Can anyone suggest me a third party tool that you have used or have heard off?
Any links to sample code that you came across so that i can get started?
Is there a plugin for Adobe Bridge that i can integrate with ASP.Net to use its functionality to create thumbnails?

I had the same requirement 3 years back and since i could not come up with a solution, the local users created a thumbnail using Adobe Bridge and then uploads it to my local web DAM tool (developed in .Net 1.1)
Currently i need to do the same for a client which will be developed in ASP.Net 2.0. But they will not use Adobe Bridge to create the thumbnails. hence i need to come up with a solution to create thumbnails on the fly when they upload the files.

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that does PDF. 
http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfthumbnail-overview.aspx
I did not come across ones that do PSD or EPS. Maybe TIFF can be converted to JPG and displayed?